# Create a musician and singer resume

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In Stack Overflow there is a functionality to maintain a developer resume.

What about musicians and singers? Is it possible to make something similar?

Comment: Do you want a similar function on this site (music practice and theory) or do you want to know how to set up resume as a musican?

Comment: a CV is 'same but different' whatever your profession…  Coder: 2 years MIT, Muso: 2 years Berklee. Coder, 18 months Goldman Sachs, Muso: 18 months MD for Hamilton. On the other hand, I've been a 'pro' muso since about 1978 & have never yet been asked for a CV...

Comment: @Olli Basically a Musician/Singer story on the site Music Practice And Theory, please

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, my dear friend... I will frank with you... For the first time, we have a match in this topic, I hope we are considered with each other from now on. No offence. :D

Comment: @all In Spanish web sites, it is common to put a entry on a blog. But from my difference markable strenght and English enthusiast, I think that a story would be factible. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CV and its successor, the Developer Story, were created to integrate the user profile with the Jobs part of Stack Overflow: [Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312452/4751173). Stack Overflow gets a lot of their income from Jobs (in fact, part of it is invested in hosting/maintaining other Stack Exchange sites!), so it makes sense to put developer effort into a related feature. Since Jobs are limited to positions in IT, it's highly unlikely to be rolled out to other sites like Music: Practice & Theory.

Comment: I see what you mean. I accept all the critics you said. Thanks.